# query-exporter doesn't connect to the Database - throws "module not found"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, db2, prometheus

I have some set of data in the IBM DB2 database which needs to be utilized as something required for metrics. To get this accomplished I'm trying to use python's export prometheus metrics from SQL - Reference here: https://pypi.org/project/query-exporter/

Inline to this I have tried to install the ibm_db module using `pip3 install ibm_db`

When I list the modules I have in the cmdline, I see it available:

[image]

And Below is my config.yaml which will establish connection to poll the data from the database for the metrics to be exported to Prometheus.

[image]

In the above for the `dsn`, I have also tried with:

`db2://user:pass@host[:port]/database` , `db2+ibm_db://user:pass@host[:port]/database`

But ended up with the same result which is show in the below.

Now I'm trying to execute the query-exporter module using the below command:

`query-exporter ~/py-query-exporter/config.yaml`

But ending up with the below error:

[image]

**Can someone help here why the ibm_db module is not getting identified? - I don't know if this issue is wider across different db module** Also, my python version is:

`vijayleom@Vijays-MacBook-Pro ~ % python -V`

`Python 3.8.11`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Trying to connect to IBM DB2

Comment: (Plese edit your question, do not use comments to add facts that should be in the question ).  What is the version of the MacOS?  Are you able to use plain python `import ibm_db` followed by a connect with a valid connection string ( just to localise the trouble area) ?

Comment: Added as recommended to the question itself. Mac version is 11.5.2(BigSur OS). And Nope, even there it fails.

`>>> import ibm_db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ibm_db'`

Comment: Appreciate the person who has down voted this question to note that this is a valid  scenario and can incur for anyone. This may be misguiding when somebody comes in for similar searches to find an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Always add pertinent facts to the question, not as comments, because comments are not searchable and are easily missed.

If you cannot `import ibm_db` and successfully run `ibm_db.connect(....)` then any tools (such as SQLAlchemy or packages that use SQLAlchemy like your query-exporter) will not work - because ibm_db underpins them.

If this is a conda environment, you should use conda to install the ibm_db because conda checks dependencies more fully than does pip. Sometimes it is necessary to upgrade the pip version also (regardless of conda).

Apart from that, there are known issues with ibm_db on MacOS , but most have workarounds by now.

Two in particular may be relevant, relating to comptibility with the c libraries (which `conda install ibm_db` should find)  and sometimes a need to export a specific value for environment variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH before running python.

Find the directory that contains clidriver, which by default gets installed with ibm_db module. By default it will be in the site-packages directory of your python environment (you can use `pip3 show ibm_db` to see the directory name ). Get the fully-qualified directory name for clidriver and append /lib to it, then use that value  ( e.g. your_clidriver_path/lib  , thus:

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=your_clidriver_path/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`  before you run your python code.

When you cannot get a workaround, try searching for matching problems and solutions on the github-issues page for python ibm_db before opening a ticket for the developers at https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues

Comment: I have the details in the question itself... Hope it has necessary information. Let me know what in specific you are looking for in the question descriptionpls.